# cannot longer share apps on latest version of Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Stock Galaxy S4 GT-I9505, latest public version of Google Play Store, now when I open an app I do see the uninstall / Open or Update buttons and a new visual showing nicer/bigger application icon and round icons showing downloads count, rating results, similar apps etc, but unfortunately no longer a button to share the app link via whatsapp / gmail etc...

Is this problem only with me or also others unable to share apps anymore from Google Play Store?

thanks and regards,
Davide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a Nexus 4 with new version of PlayStore. I can see a "Share" button just below the "Reviews" section. You can check once again if you have missed it :)

[image]